# Java Robot Moves Mouse To The Incorrect Coordinates

Tags: java, mouse, screen-resolution, awtrobot

```
public class R0b0t 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  
    {
        Robot robot;
        robot = new Robot();

        robot.mouseMove(50,50);
    }
}
```

The code above is a simple program that moves the mouse to the coordinates (50,50) on my screen. It works fine when I execute the program on my PC.

But when I run the executable jar file on my Windows tablet, the coordinates moves to (40, 40). I'm checking the coordinates with a "cursor position" software. I've tried different `mouseMove` coordinates but the mouse still moves to a different location on my tablet.

How do I solve this problem? I believe it has something to do with the screen resolution on my tablet because I also tried using another software that detects what color the mouse is pointing to, and the color detect doesn't really match with what I'm pointing to.